# How to find out the Child views exact position from it's Parents view by convertPoint toview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgpoint

Please take have a look to the below image :

[image]

Here all I want to get the `CGPoint` of my `UITextField` **C** perspective to the main `UIViewController` **Z**. I was converting it's position from the main `UIViewController` **Z**, like this :

```
 CGPoint pointInTable = [Cell.inputTextField.superview convertPoint:Cell.inputTextField.frame.origin toView:self.view];
```

But I think I have to convert every single child View according to it's immidiate parent view. But how?

If anyone know the answer, please share it with me.
A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert directly between any two views that are in the same hierarchy.

```
[self.view convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:Cell.inputTextField];
```

Comment: @Cy-4AH, thanks for the edit.  That's what happens when I just copy+paste from the question.